# How to print out all characters in MSSQL field -- CR LF issues

Tags: sql-server, char

I have an MSSQL table that keeps getting 'BLANK' entries in fields -- I'm not sure if this is happening programmatically or because of user entry. It will display as a little 'BLOCK', but field otherwise looks blank. If I COPY and PASTE into notepad++ and show line characters, I get a space and a CRLF (sometimes more than one). I want to know EXACTLY everything this field has it it. There seems to be another value AFTER the CRLF that isn't showing up in Notepad. If I search the field using

```
WHERE (e_text LIKE '% ' + CHAR(13) + '' + CHAR(10) + '%')
```

I get results. If I search using

```
WHERE (e_text LIKE ' ' + CHAR(13) + '' + CHAR(10) + '%')
```

I get results.

But if I search using:

```
WHERE (e_text LIKE '% ' + CHAR(13) + '' + CHAR(10) + '')
```

I don't get results. So, using no wildcard at the end, SQL seems to say there is another value.

[image: SQL DISPLAY and NOTEPAD++]

Comment: The last predicate you provided, `WHERE (e_text LIKE '% ' + CHAR(13) + '' + CHAR(10) + '')` is looking for a string where there is a space before the CRLF. What happens if you just use `WHERE (e_text LIKE CHAR(13) + '' + CHAR(10) + '')`?

Comment: Aron, sorry - -meant to include that too -- it finds nothing. There are apparently trailing values not showing up in my copy/paste to notepad++. I just ran: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx (Using ASCII and CHAR to print ASCII values from a string)

The result is: 32,13,10,10,32,32,32,32

So, notepad is missing a CR and four trailing blanks vs. this SQL printout.

Comment: But if I search for:
WHERE (e_text LIKE CHAR(13) + '' + CHAR(10) + ''+ CHAR(10) +'    ')

I still get nothing. I tried ending with one space and %, also, no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is that you're not trimming values before inserting them into the database.  The example below can help you identify what columns have data.  I'm doing the following:

1. replace newlines with spaces
2. trim excess spaces on the left
3. trim eccess spaces on the right
4. Does that equal empty string?  If so, then there is nothing in here.

Sample code:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (field1 varchar(100));    
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES 
('I am not null'),
('   '),
(' 

'),
('not null with new line

'),
('not null with trailing spaces        ');


SELECT *, CASE 
WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(field1, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''))) = '' THEN 'column can be trimmed to nothing' ELSE 'column has something' end
FROM @tbl
```

[image]

Comment: There are a few cases where SSMS will show blank space with some UTF characters. So a length check should help with those edge cases (where trim would fail)

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help correct this programmatically -- I'm just trying to go through and clean this stuff up (dev will deal with the trimming). I just want to know how to find out what EXACTLY SQL has in that cell.

Comment: if you want to know EXACTLY what it has, then select the data out with a tool other than SSMS.  Or, select to file.  I'm guessing though that you don't really care about anything that can be trimmed to nothing, so you could use something like what I wrote to help you update the data in the database.

Comment: Maybe another way I could ask this -- I want to find any field with ONLY whitespace, and nothing else. If it has ANY other characters, a letter 'D' or a '?' -- anything else, I don't want to touch it, even if it has other white space in it.

Comment: Yep, so just move what I provided into a where clause: `SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(field1, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), ''))) = ''`

Comment: Thanks jhilden -- I added ----> and (field <> '') <----, because I don't need fields that are just blank.